# Snowflake alternative to MYSQL FORMAT function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have precision stored in a database table. We want to round the amount for each currency as per its own precision. In Mysql this can be done by using FORMAT but I am unable to do this in Snowflake.

e.g in MYSQL `FORMAT(2.34, table.precision)` returns 2.340 if the precision is 3 and 2.34 if the precision is 2.

Can this be done in Snowflake db ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    2.34124544 AS f
    ,round(2.34124544, r) 
    ,'99.'|| RPAD('', r, '9') AS form
    ,TO_CHAR(f,form)
FROM VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3) v(r);
```

gives:

```
F           ROUND(2.34124544, R)    FORM      TO_CHAR(F,FORM)
2.34124544  2.00000000              99.       2.
2.34124544  2.30000000              99.9      2.3
2.34124544  2.34000000              99.99     2.34
2.34124544  2.34100000              99.999    2.341
```

So you can round to the precision you want, or build a format string and format the out also. and how it's working.

Thus compacted up:

```
SELECTTO_CHAR(2.34124544, '99.'|| RPAD('', r, '9') )
FROM VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3) v(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to format it for output, your best call would be:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html - this allows entering a format string

the very last example in the doc demonstrates the use.

Comment: Thanks, i did tried and it has the same problem that you can make it dynamic based on a table column.

Comment: maybe try to explain what exactly you're trying to achieve? as in full usecase?